# error for blocking get by CORS for login using React and PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, cors

I am working on login  module,in front-end is in React and back-end is in PHP but getting CORS eror.

my Login.js code below:

```
 UserLoginFunction = () =>{     
     const { UserEmail }  = this.state ;
     const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/users-react/api/contact/login.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
      email: UserEmail,
      password: UserPassword
      })
       }).then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
     if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
            {
               this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', { Email: UserEmail });
             }
            else{
        alert(responseJson);
            }
       }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
      <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
    <button onClick={this.UserLoginFunction} >Login</button>
```

in my login.php file i have putted below headers:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, 
Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

I tried all these above headers but still getting error(from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.)

please have a look and let me know

Comment: "I tried so many option for allow headers" - Perhaps you should share those failed attempts rather than non-related working code. You also forgot to say what the error is. Also, do you *need* cross-origin requests?

Comment: yes getting from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy error

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: During development you use webpack dev server so you can set a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) in your package.json. When you publish your code it is likely to run on the same server so you should use root relative urls such as `api/entity/id`